# Dropping database table

Tags: mysql

While I was importing production data into my development database, something went off and I now have two database tables that are similar, differing only that one contains the db name as a table prefix.

In this case, I have a database `rmstg`, and two tables

```
main_stratkeys
rmstg.main_stratkeys
```

How can I drop the latter table?

`DROP TABLE rmstg.main_stratkeys` drops the first table, but not the latter.

`DROP TABLE rmstg.rmstg.main_stratkeys` returns a SQL syntax error with the inner `.rmstg.` declaration.

Comment: try placing ` around the table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using backquotes:

```
drop table `rmstg.main_stratkeys`;
```

or

```
drop table rmstg.`rmstg.main_stratkeys`;
```

Comment: Using backquotes was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the CLI:

```
USE rmstg;
DROP TABLE main_stratkeys;
```

Is also an option.

Backquotes should also be helpful, dunno that syntax, exactly, though.

Comment: "That syntax" is pretty much what you said. Put backquotes (`) in front and after each identifier.

Comment: Oh, I meant the single-command to directly drop like @gordon-linoff 's answer.  I was thinking ```DROP `database`.`table` ```, a case that he didn't use.